# Custom Colorful QR Code generation by embedding Logo

Tags: c#, asp.net, qr-code

I am developing a web based application using Asp.Net where I need to generate Colorful QR Codes by embedding client's logo inside the QR code. I need something similar to the following link: http://mashable.com/2011/07/23/creative-qr-codes/

Can anyone please suggest some free libraries for .net which I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is implemented using the library shared at https://qrcodenet.codeplex.com